# pip install error: package directory does not exist

Tags: python, pip

I've looked at similar questions, but with no luck of answer, I have the following structure

```
├── README.rst
├── setup.py
└── my_package
    ├── conf.py
    ├── sub_module1
    │   └── __init__.py
    │   └── some_code.py
    ├── sub_module2
    │   └── __init__.py
    │   └── some_other_code.py
    ├── some_main_code.py
    └── __init__.py
```

And my `setup.py` looks something like

```
..
setup(name=..
      ...
      packages=find_packages('my_package')
```

When installing I get the following error

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /some_path/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-f7hcw6xa/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-f7hcw6xa/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-req-build-f7hcw6xa/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-f7hcw6xa/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-req-build-f7hcw6xa/pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-req-build-f7hcw6xa/pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-req-build-f7hcw6xa/pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to /tmp/pip-req-build-f7hcw6xa/pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-req-build-f7hcw6xa/pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-req-build-f7hcw6xa/pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    error: package directory 'sub_module1' does not exist
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

If `sub_module1` is there, and has an **init**.py file in it - why wouldn't the installation recognize it?

Comment: try: `packages=setuptools.find_packages(),` and mention name of package in `name=<<name>>`

Comment: Still an error though a different one containing   `and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:
  
      ''`

Comment: Yes, either `find_packages(include='my_package')` or `find_packages()`. Since `find_packages('my_package')` means `my_package(where='my_package')` which does something else and it clearly isn't what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Kudos to [sinoroc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11138259/sinoroc) for pointing out there of course is more than one solution to this issue.

**Solution #1**

The error message tells you that the interpreter thinks you have a package called 'sub_module1'. Since that is obviously intended to be a module and not a package, you can see that you are missing one level in your directory structure for the way you are currently trying to make use of find_packages().

You could add a "src" folder to the structure of your project. Then you would have to do something like:

```
mkdir src
mv my_package src/
```

And inside setup.py point find_packages to 'src' instead of 'my_package':

```
packages=find_packages(where="src"),
package_dir={'': 'src'},
```

**Solution #2**

Alternatively you could try to use find_packages without any parameter at all (as suggested by https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/):

```
packages=find_packages()
```

This did not work for me when I set up my package and in the long run it turned out that I would have been off better with the src/ solution anyways. That is why my initial version of an answer assumed you would want to add src/.

**Personal Conclusio**

Keep in mind that if you might have more packages in the future, want to add scripts to your package or do anything more complex than just one package it might be wise to go with src/. I am aware this has been topic of discussions for years that's why I call this a "personal conclusio".

Comment: Not sure, that's what the user wants. Additionally user would need to modify `package_dir` as well, if they really did want the `src` layout.

Comment: I like this version of the answer better. I changed my vote.